# Multigroup SEM: How to interpret regression coefficients?

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am carrying out a multigroup SEM with two independent subgroups (approx. 240 observations per subgroup). I have already tested measurement invariance (i.e., configural, metric, scalar & strict invariance), and came to the conclusion that full measurement invariance is upheld. Also, according to the goodness-of-fit test, the model fits the data well (both for the full sample as well as for the two subgroups).

Now, I want to test differences in the structural models. For starters, I constrained the regression coefficients and compared the constrained model with the unconstrained. Based on chi-square and CFI differences, the models are invariant.

However, when comparing the regression coefficients of the unconstrained models for both subgroups I see that one path is significant in group 1 and non-significant in group 2 (95% confidence interval). In the full sample model, the path appears to be significant.

How should I interpret the non-significance in group 2? Can I just ignore it and ascribe the effect to a lack of statistical power for group 2?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It is not a matter of ignoring, the effect is just not significant in group 2. No?

Comment: I would have thought so too. However, when carrying out a structural invariance test (comparing the saturated multigroup model with a constrained model in which all regression parameters are set equal across groups) results show that the difference in models is not significant. This would mean that the regression coefficients are not statistically different across groups - how can that be?

Comment: Welcome @Elisa! What you're observing is a common and often misunderstood possible outcome of statistical modeling ) and testing when using frequentist methods (i.e., those with p-values), including but not limited to SEM. There are many explanations of this possibility, but "The Difference Between “Significant” and “Not Significant” is not Itself Statistically Significant" by Gelman and Hal (2006) is a popular one: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf