# How to interpret PLS-MGA’s results based on the significance of the corresponding group specific path coefficients

Tags: statistical-significance, structural-equation-modeling, partial-least-squares

As a more general follow-up question to [Elisa](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/343440)’s [post on “[h]ow to interpret regression coefficients”](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/558563) when carrying out a PLS-[structural-equation-modeling](/questions/tagged/structural-equation-modeling) multigroup analysis (PLS-MGA), when comparing group-specific parameter estimates $\gamma_{.}$, which are (partially)
measurement invariant, for significant differences, how to interpret the results based on the significance of the corresponding group specific path coefficients?

In particular, let us assume that

1. an observation $S$ is given, comprising two independent groups $A$ and $B$, i.e. $A\,\dot{\cup}\,B = S$,
2. a respective $S$’s, $A$’s, and $B$’s structural model’s relationship coefficient is denoted as $\gamma_{S}$, $\gamma_{A}$, and $\gamma_{B}$, respectively, and
3. $\gamma_{A}$ and $\gamma_{B}$ are significantly different.

Now I wonder how to interpret the PLS-MGA’s results when

1. $\gamma_{S}$ as well as $\gamma_{A}$ are significant, but $\gamma_{B}$ is non-significant and
2. both $\gamma_{A}$ and $\gamma_{B}$ are non-significant, but $\gamma_{S}$ is either significant or non-significant

at a certain significance level?